# No Porto as vogais são pronunciadas como ditongos antes do R?

Tags: português-europeu

Uma das impressões que tenho no sotaque do Porto é que as vogais não são pronunciadas de forma plana, como se fossem ditonguizadas.

Por exemplo, *o que estás a fazer no Porto?* soa-me *o que está a faziâr no Puârto?*

É mesmo assim que pronunciam ou é impressão minha?

Comment: Tens certeza de que soam como ditongos crescentes (*-iâr, -uâr-*)? Para mim soam como ditongos decrescentes (*fazeir, Pourto*). A primeira opção (a dos crescentes) parece ser mais um hispanófono tentando falar português (*hacier, Puerto*).

Answer (score 2):

Eu acho que há uma tendência para a nasalização e prolongamento dos «o» fechados, não necessariamente antes do r.
Bom também fica "boum", por exemplo.

> Este binho do puorto é mesmo boum!

Aliás, de vogais em geral:

- Alguns «o» fechados ficam «u»: «[cumbersa](https://priberam.pt/dlpo/conversa)»
- Alguns «e» fechados ficam «ei»: «[bermeilho](https://priberam.pt/dlpo/cascalho)», «[beim](https://priberam.pt/dlpo/bem)»;
- Alguns «a» abertos ficam «ai»: «[cascailho](https://priberam.pt/dlpo/cascalho)»;
- Etc.

Mas decide por ti próprio; soa assim:

"Vai no Batalha" - Teatro de Marionetas do Porto
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tXrzK9Xbzvg

> Excerto de "Vai no Batalha"-Teatro de Marionetas do Porto. A epopeia de Fredo Brilhantinas para obter a licença de "arrumbador de biaturas ligeiras na cambra municipal do puerto".

O Fredo Brilhantinas tem um sotaque portuense *bem* cerrado, e usa muitas expressões locais. É uma representação muito fiel. <sup>[1]</sup>
O Senhor Moutinho tem um sotaque limpo.

---

[1] Note-se que o sotaque portuense é algo raro hoje em dia: tanto devido à influência dos média; como à uniformização da linguagem devida ao sistema de ensino; como à diluição de regionalismos devido ao êxodo rural e às migrações inter-cidades.
Usam-se ainda bastantes expressões, mas o sotaque perde-se. :(

Comment: Também percebo ditonguização nalguns dialetos brasileiros, mas sempre em sílabas fechadas (terminadas em consoantes). Como, na língua portuguesa, as únicas consoantes que encerram sílaba produtivamente são `⟨r, s~z, l, n~m⟩`, acaba que são nesses contextos que *"bem"* vira *"beim"* e *"vez"* vira *"vêis"*. Quanto ao *"verme**i**lho"*, talvez seja a conservação de um traço arcaico, já que este `/i/` já ocorria antigamente (*"vermelho < \*verme**i**lo < *vermeclo < vermiclum"*, o mesmo com cascalho e outros).

Comment: Vejo bastante ditongação nesse vídeo mesmo sem ser antes do R: sinhuâr,  quiâ, purfeitamiante.

Comment: @Seninha no Porto, «vez» mantém o mesmo e: «bêz»; mas o resto sim, faz todo o sentido... no que consigo acompanhar. :)

Comment: @RuiFonseca por alguma razão cismei que a tua pergunta era só sobre o «o»... tenho de re-escrever isto amanhã, com foco nas vogais e não só no «o». Vou ter de ler também sobre ditonguização, que pareço ter *metido água*. Amanhã. :)

Comment: @Seninha - Em São Paulo creio que há ditongação mesmo em sílabas sem consoante pós-vocálica: *intereisse*, *cachourro*, *bataata*. Minha impressão é que as vogais tônicas foram alongadas para reforçar o acento, e depois o final da consoante longa "caiu" para uma mais fechada: rabanete -> rabane:te -> rabaneite.

Comment: @LuísHenrique -- Bom, o falar carioca também alonga vogais e, por vezes, as ditonguiza. Imagino que o que ocorre no falar paulistano seja parecido. Esse é o traço marcante do dialeto que é sempre satirizado na comédia (ver [aqui](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xcYlrytrtpQ)).